# Not enough cores to deploy resource group error on Azure for Students

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-resource-group

I am very new to Azure. I have an Azure for Students subscription and I'm trying to create an Apache Kafka cluster using Azure HDInsight. I selected West Europe as my region. I'm using this resource as a guide: https://lenadroid.github.io/posts/kafka-hdinsight-and-spark-databricks.html

The first step was to create a resource group, which I managed to do. The next step is to deploy is, which consistently fails. The error is there are not enough cores: 26 cores are required, but 0 are available.

```
{
"status":"Failed",
"error":
    {
    "code":"DeploymentFailed",
    "message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
    "details":[
        {
        "code":"BadRequest",
        "message":"{\r\n  \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n  \"message\": \"User SubscriptionId '29bb2797-a6e9-4412-90da-52863c7579ad' does not have cores left to create resource 'kafka-kafkaclustertest1'. Required: 26, Available: 0.\"\r\n}"}
     ]
    }
}
```

Looking at Usage + quotas, I'm at 100% usage of Network Watchers (1 out of 1). I tried disabling the Network Watcher to no avail.
My subscription is not eligible for a quota increase.

My questions are:

- Does Azure for Students, with its $100 credit, support the services I will need: Resource Group, Virtual Networks, HDInsight?
- If yes, do I have to configure/activate my subscription credit somehow?
- Could the issue be related to the region? How do I make sure West Europe has enough available cores? Is it reasonable to try different regions?
- Can I configure my Kafka resource group to requires less cores?
- Are there easier ways to deploy a Kafka cluster, perhaps on other cloud providers?

I would very much appreciate some guidance -- thanks!

Comment: The easier way to get Kafka would be to use EventHubs or link Confluent Cloud to your Azure (or other cloud) account. More specifically, HDInsight brings up a bunch of other Hadoop stuff that isn't related to Kafka

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a subscription support question, not a programming question.

Comment: Please open a billing support ticket to discuss this further. This isn't something for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, you cannot create the Azure HDInsight cluster with the Student subscription.

**Reason:** With an Azure Student subscription, you will initially be able to access only Azure services that are available with a free tier of service use.

For more limitations, refer to the below links:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0144p/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/students/

> You may want to look at a `pay-as-you-go` subscription as this should allow you to deploy a HDInsight cluster, however, may not allow you to utilize the benefits of a student subscription.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0003p/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0023p/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/hdinsight/